# Don't let use -(id)init; method

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, init

I'm developing an app for iPhone 3.1.3.

I have the following class:

```
@interface Pattern : NSObject {

    NSMutableArray* shapes;
    NSMutableArray* locations;
    CGSize bounds;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSMutableArray* shapes;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSMutableArray* locations;

- (id) initWithNumShapes:(int)numShapes screenSize:(CGSize)screenSize;
- (void) addObject:(Object2D*) newObject;

@end
```

I don't want to let programmers use `-(id)init;` because I need to setup my fields (shape, locations, bounds) on every initialization.

**I don't want to let programmers use this:**

```
Pattern* myPattern = [[Pattern alloc] init];
```

I know how to implement:

```
- (id) initWithNumShapes:(int)numShapes screenSize:(CGSize) screenSize{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        shapes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numShapes];
        locations = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numShapes];
        bounds = screenSize;
    }
    return (self);
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

raise an exception if somebody uses the plain `init`

```
- (id)init {
    [NSException raise:@"MBMethodNotSupportedException" format:@"\"- (id)init\" is not supported. Please use the designated initializer \"- (id)initWithNumShapes:screenSize:\""];
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override the init function and give default values from it if you have:

```
- (id)init {
    return [self initWith....];
}
```

If you don't want init at all, still override and throw some kind of exception saying not to use init.

```
- (id)init {
    NSAssert(NO, @"Please use other method ....");
    return nil;
}
```

This will always give an exception if anyone tried to call `init`.

I would suggest to use the former case though, and have some default values.

Comment: The NSAssert-blocked `init` method should still `return nil` to avoid warnings. 
Also if you enable the `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTION` pre-porcessor macro in your release configuration it will only warn the programmers in debug mode and not be compiled into release builds.

Comment: Fixed the return part :). Regarding assertion, I feel that during coding, the programmer would build in debug mode only. At least he should. But point taken :).

Answer (score 0):

Its always the same schema. Just call init on your superclass (NSObject).

```
- (id) initWithNumShapes:(int)numShapes screenSize:(CGSize)screenSize {
     if(self == [super init]) {
          // Custom Init your properties
          myNumShapes = numShapes;
          myScreenSize = screenSize;
     }
     return self;
}
```

Comment: No, sorry. I haven't explained very well. I know how to implement `- (id) initWithNumShapes:(int)numShapes screenSize:(CGSize)screenSize`. I want to don't let programmers use `-(id)init;`